# Why Special Character in Variable Name Gives Error?

Tags: freemarker

I have the following freemarker file:

```
<#ftl strip_whitespace="true">
...
<#assign wän = ...>
```

If I run such a freemarker on one server, it's working well, If I run it on a different server, I get this:

> freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template
> "template-name.ftl" in line 15, column 100: Lexical error: encountered
> "\ufffd" (65533), after "".   at
> freemarker.core.TokenMgrError.toParseException(TokenMgrError.java:247)[445:org.freemarker.freemarker:2.3.23.stable]

The version of my freemarker is 2.3.23.stable.

Any hint what I should do to be able to run this template on the bugy server?

N.B. I run my freemarker template from Apache Karaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your templates are in some non-UTF-8 charset (maybe ISO-8859-1), but the `defaultEncoding` configuration setting of FreeMarker is not set, so it uses the default of the operation system. Where the OS default is the non-UTF-8 charset, it will work. But where the OS default is UTF-8, the characters above code 127 will be seen as invalid UTF-8 byte sequences, and Java will substitute them with a U+FFFD character.

Update: Another way of getting U+FFFD characters is reading a non-US-ASCII (such as UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc.) file with US-ASCII charset, as there character codes above 127 are illegal.

Setting the default charset:

- In java: `configuration.setDefaultEncoding("...")`, where `configuration` is the `freemarker.template.Configuration` object your are already using
- In `.properties` file (if FreeMarker is configured from that): `defaultEncoding=...`
- Per template: with `<#ftl encoding="...">` header

Comment: hmmm.... actually, in both environments I have set UTF-8 as the default system encoding.

Comment: What charset do the template files actually use? Like if you look at it with some text editor, not via FreeMarker.

Comment: After some investigation, I realize is the OSGI environment the one to be blamed. I set -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 at startup and it runs fine. But thanks, your points helped me to trace the issue.

Comment: The error seems to be caused by decoding non-UTF-8 template file with UTF-8 charset, so I wonder how did adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` help there?

Comment: The error was present because I decoded UTF-8 encoded template with US-ASCII. There were characters out of US-ASCII range.

Comment: Indeed. Added this to my answer.